# git describe a tag that match a glob pattern

Tags: git, glob, git-describe

I have few tags with the following patterns in chronological order:

```
0.0.3.156-alpha+2
0.0.3.154
0.0.3.153
build-.139
build-.140
build-.142
build-0.0.1.28
build-0.0.1.29
```

I need to get the latest tag that match the pattern *number.number.number.number* hence `0.0.3.154` in this case.
The git command `git descrive --match=<pattern>` will find the latest tag that matches that pattern. But since  here is a **glob** (see [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77d21f29eaddb1fbe82e013ea42d4e0180bbdda2/Documentation/git-describe.txt#L91-L99)) and not a **regex**.

Could you show me the correct glob pattern to match the above?

Comment: Why cant you pipe the output and use sed or other editing utility and tokenize only the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try git describe --tags --match "[0-1000].[0-1000].[0-1000]*"
and if you want to delete the last part use -cut ...

Comment: Can you be more precise about what the OP should do?

Comment: Thats not how it works, [0-1000] would match  "0" to "1" or "0" or "0" or" 0 (yes it is a redundant pattern). [0-456] would match "0" to "4" or "5" or "6"